# Unhandled Runtime Error On Axelar Examples

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, axelar

I want to use this link:
https://github.com/axelarnetwork/axelar-examples/tree/main/examples-web
but when i run it i get this error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

Error: invalid contract address or ENS name (argument="addressOrName", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)

Source
src/types/factories/contracts/call-contract/MessageSender\_\_factory.ts (108:11) @ Function.connect

106 | signerOrProvider: Signer | Provider
107 | ): MessageSender {

> 108 | return new Contract(address, \_abi, signerOrProvider) as MessageSender;

      |           ^

109 | }
110 | }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the example running with the following

`npm ci` for dependencies

`npm run setup` for env examples-web directory.

`npm run deploy` for deploying locally

`npm run dev` for frontend